# RcppRoll or CumSum to lag with dynamic window

Tags: r, data.table, rcpp

There must be an easy, possible recursive solution, for the following problem. I would very much appreciate, if anyone can help:

I use data.table and RcppRoll to calculate the weekly sales in qualified weeks within the past 26 weeks for each product. With a window of 26, this works fine, as long as # of current week > 26. However, when # of current week is <= 26, I want to use a window of size 26, 25, ..., and so on.

The formular would be: baseline sales = sum over 26 (or less) weeks of sales (before current week, in qualified weeks only), divided by # of qualified weeks

Here is some code to create test data:

```
library("data.table")
library("RcppRoll")

products <- seq(1:10) #grouping variable
weeks <- seq(1:100) #weeks
sales <- round(rchisq(1000, 2),0) #sales
countweek <- round(runif(1000, 0,1),0) #1, if qualified weeks

data <- as.data.table(cbind(merge(weeks,products,all=T),sales,countweek))
names(data) <- c("week","product","sales","countweek")
data <- data[order(product,week)]

data[,pastsales:=shift(RcppRoll::roll_sumr(sales*countweek,26L,fill=0),1L,0,"lag"),by=.(product)]
data[,rollweekcount:=shift(RcppRoll::roll_sumr(countweek,26L,fill=0),1L,0,"lag"),by=.(product)]
data[,baseline:=pastsales/rollweekcount]
```

You can see the break at week line 26 for product 1. After line 26, I get the desired results:

```
> data[product == 1]
     week product sales countweek pastsales rollweekcount baseline
...
 20:   20       1     1         0         0             0      NaN
 21:   21       1     2         0         0             0      NaN
 22:   22       1     1         1         0             0      NaN
 23:   23       1     0         0         0             0      NaN
 24:   24       1     3         1         0             0      NaN
 25:   25       1     5         1         0             0      NaN
 26:   26       1     5         1         0             0      NaN
 27:   27       1     1         1        44            13 3.384615
 28:   28       1     0         1        45            14 3.214286
 29:   29       1     5         0        44            14 3.142857
 30:   30       1     0         1        44            14 3.142857
 31:   31       1     3         1        44            14 3.142857
 32:   32       1     4         0        42            14 3.000000
...
```

Comment: `Error in order(product, week) : object 'product' not found`

Comment: Should work now, with data.table included

Comment: You can use `fifelse` with `cumsum` like `data[, pastsales := shift(fifelse(is.na(x <- roll_sumr(sales*countweek, 26L)), cumsum(sales*countweek), x), 1L, 0), .(product)][, 
    rollweekcount := shift(fifelse(is.na(x <- roll_sumr(countweek, 26L)), cumsum(sales*countweek), x), 1L, 0), .(product)][, 
        baseline := pastsales/rollweekcount]` but it is not going to be faster than using `data.table::frollsum`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an "adaptive" window width. Not sure about RcppRoll, but the more recent versions of data.table has `frollsum` which can do this

```
data[, pastsales := shift(frollsum(sales*countweek, pmin(1:.N, 26L), adaptive = TRUE),
                          1L, 0, "lag"),
     by = .(product)]

data[, rollweekcount := shift(frollsum(countweek,  pmin(1:.N,  26L), adaptive = TRUE), 
                              1L, 0, "lag"), 
     by = .(product)]
```

Comment: ICT, is "adaptive" analogous to `zoo`'s "partial"?

Comment: Yes, but there is a difference. With zoo, you can just put `partial = TRUE` and leave `width` as a length-1 integer. With data.table, you're required to specify the vector of all window widths.